# list items of HashMap in a list view displays only the last items

Tags: android, listview

I have an issue with the listview items. All the listview items display the last value of the hash map for all the listview items while clicking on the listview. How to resolve this issue.I have done the coding like this.

Code:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try {
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(
                url);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        String jsonResp = EntityUtils.toString(response
                .getEntity());
        Log.d("HTTP", "Rsponse : " + jsonResp);

        if (jsonResp != null) {

            JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject(jsonResp);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject1.getJSONArray("values");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject2 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                         firstname = jsonObject2.getString(firstname);
                         lastname = jsonObject2.getString(lastname);
                         headline = jsonObject2.getString(headline);
                         pictureUrl = jsonObject2.getString(pictureUrl);
                         id = jsonObject2.getString(id);

                    JSONObject jsonObject3 = jsonObject2.getJSONObject("siteStandardProfileRequest");
                    url = jsonObject3.getString("url");

                }
                Log.d("HTTP", "firstname : " + firstname + "\n" + "lastName :"
                        + lastname + "\n" + "headline : " + headline + "\n"
                        + "pictureUrl :" + pictureUrl + "\n" + "id :"
                        + id + "\n" + "Url :" + url);
                contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                contact.put(TAG_FNAME, firstname);
                contact.put(TAG_LNAME, lastname);
                contact.put(TAG_HLINE, headline);
                contact.put(TAG_PURL, pictureUrl);
                contact.put(TAG_URL, url);
                contactList.add(contact);

            }
        } else {
            Log.e("HTTP", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            HomeActivity.this, contactList,
            R.layout.list_item, new String[]{TAG_FNAME}, new int[]{R.id.textView1});
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Collections.sort(contactList, new Comparator<Map<String, String>>() {
        public int compare(final Map<String, String> o1, final Map<String, String> o2) {
            return o1.get("firstname").compareTo(o2.get("firstname"));
        }

    });
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    lv.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                View view, int position, long ids) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    SingleListActivity.class);

            i.putExtra("id", id);
            i.putExtra("firstname", firstname);
            i.putExtra("lastname", lastname);
            i.putExtra("headline", headline);
            i.putExtra("pictureUrl", pictureUrl);
            i.putExtra("url", url);
            Log.v("Pass", "id :" + id + "\n" + "firstname :" + firstname + "\n"
                    + "lastname :" + lastname + "\n" + "headline :" + headline
                    + "\n" + "pictureUrl :" + pictureUrl + "\n"
                    + "siteStandardProfileRequest" + url);
            startActivity(i);


        }
    });
}
```

Comment: contactList, where you initialized this variable?

Comment: have you seen contact list value and also please sort list before given list to adapter?

Comment: why HashMap<String, String> contact = contactList.get(position); is there inside listview onClick(). You are not using it anywhere. This is called Shadowing. May be that can be a reason.

Comment: It also displaying the last connection values for all the litliems....@Spurdow

Answer (score 1):

I have used the same ListView and I might be able to help you.

1) I would delete the first line (**HashMap contact = new HashMap();**) and add in the loop below as you need for every record a new HashMap. Thus, replace the line:

**`contact = new HashMap<String, String>();`**

with:

`HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();`

Additionally, I would use the following for

`private static final String TAG_FName = "FirstName";`

and then at JSOn Object,

`String fname = c.getString(TAG_FName)`

And later:

`ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Activity.this, contactList, R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_FName, },new int[] { R.id.TEXTVIEW});`

Comment: I guess that is enough for you to change the your code. I am already doing much more things in the same class, so I guess i would just make you confused. Do the changes I told you.

Comment: I changed, but didn't get the values accordingly. It displays only the last connection details....@artiintel69

Comment: Well I guess it is the error in the adding of the values into the HashMap. Try to go over it again, do multiple check on the way.